# Recover data from DMG image of external drive

Tags: disk-utility, data-recovery, dmg

I have a DMG file which was created for an external APFS drive using Disk Utility. The DMG file is 250GB.

The output from Disk Utility when the DMG was created

```
Reading GPT Partition Data (Primary GPT Table: 2).
(CRC32 $2BAA529C: GPT.Partition Data (Primary GPT Table : 2)
Reading (Apple Free: 3).
(CRC32 $00000000: (Apple Free: 3))
Reading EFI System Partition (C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B : 4)
Da SH-08,809372029 F, System Partian(C12A723728-FRIE-1102-


Reading Untitled 2 (Apple_APFS : 5)...
  (CRC32 $811EEA88: Untitled 2 (Apple_APFS : 5))
Reading (Apple_Free : 6)...
  (CRC32 $00000000: (Apple_Free : 6))
Reading GPT Partition Data (Backup GPT Table : 7)...
  (CRC32 $2BAA529C: GPT Partition Data (Backup GPT Table : 7))
Reading GPT Header (Backup GPT Header : 8)
  (CRC32 $EDDB9CBB: GPT Header (Backup GPT Header : 8))
Adding resources...
Elapsed Time: 2h 42m 26.569s
File size: 247610485606 bytes, Checksum: CRC32 $B12EF475
Sectors processed: 488397168, 483614211 copied
Speed: 24.2Mbytes/sec
Savings: 1.0%
Operation successful.
```

After creating the DMG, I mounted it to be sure and then formatted the external disk. The timestamp on the DMG is from the creation time so it hasn't been modified.

When I try opening it using DiskImageMounter, it says Filesystem Not Found the first time, and then on subsequent opens it says input/output error.

```
$ hdiutil attach -ignorebadchecksums ADATA\ ED600\ Media.dmg
hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable file systems
```

```
$ hdiutil attach -noverify ADATA\ ED600\ Media.dmg
hdiutil: attach failed - Input/output error
```

If I run the hdiutil command with sudo I get this output

```
$ sudo hdiutil imageinfo ADATA\ ED600\ Media.dmg
Password:
Class Name: CRawDiskImage
Size Information:
    Total Bytes: 247610608128
    Compressed Ratio: 1
    Sector Count: 483614469
    Total Non-Empty Bytes: 247610608128
    Compressed Bytes: 247610608128
    Total Empty Bytes: 0
Checksum Type: none
Format: UDRW
partitions:
    partition-scheme: none
    block-size: 512
    appendable: false
    partitions:
        0:
            partition-name: whole disk
            partition-start: 0
            partition-synthesized: true
            partition-length: 483614469
            partition-hint: unknown partition
    burnable: false
Format Description: raw read/write
Checksum Value:
Properties:
    Encrypted: false
    Kernel Compatible: true
    Checksummed: false
    Software License Agreement: false
    Partitioned: false
    Compressed: no
Segments:
    0: /Users/xxx/Desktop/s/ADATA ED600 Media.dmg
Backing Store Information:
    URL: file:///Users/xxx/Desktop/s/ADATA%20ED600%20Media.dmg
    Name: ADATA ED600 Media.dmg
    Class Name: CBSDBackingStore
Resize limits (per hdiutil resize -limits):
 min     cur     max
483614469   483614469   483614469
```

I've tried to convert it to an IMG file using

```
hdiutil convert
```

And had the same result as with the original DMG.

And I've tried to restore it to a physical disk using dd

```
hdid -nomount "ADATA%20ED600%20Media.dmg"

dd if=/dev/disk3 of=/dev/disk2 bs=131072
```

And the physical disk shows up as uninitialised and macOS asks me to format it.

How do I recover my data from this DMG file now? If the file is 250GB the bits with my data have to be in there right?

---

Output of hdiutil attach -verbose

```
Initializing…
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CEncryptedEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CUDIFEncoding
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CSegmentedUDIFEncoding
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe stat() failed.  No such file or directory.
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score        1, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIFileEncodingInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CSegmentedUDIFRawEncoding
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CUDIFDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score        0, CSparseBundleDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score        0, CSparseDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score      100, CRawDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score     -100, CShadowedDiskImage
DIDiskImageInstantiatorProbe: interface  6, score     -100, CWrappedDiskImage
DIDiskImageNewWithBackingStore: CRawDiskImage
DIDiskImageNewWithBackingStore: instantiator returned 0
Attaching…
Mounting…
2021-08-29 01:03:06.104 diskimages-helper[96309:1726667] DIHelperHDID serveImage: attaching drive
{
    autodiskmount = 1;
    "hdiagent-drive-identifier" = "8BBB11DD-D8A7-48EA-BD13-36CA2B776EB3";
    "unmount-timeout" = 0;
}
2021-08-29 01:03:06.105 diskimages-helper[96309:1726667] DIHelperHDID serveImage: connecting to myDrive 0x441B
2021-08-29 01:03:06.106 diskimages-helper[96309:1726667] DIHelperHDID serveImage: register _readBuffer 0x7fd4ae900000
2021-08-29 01:03:06.106 diskimages-helper[96309:1726667] DIHelperHDID serveImage: activating drive port 17675
2021-08-29 01:03:06.106 diskimages-helper[96309:1726667] DIHelperHDID serveImage: set cache enabled=TRUE returned FAILURE.
2021-08-29 01:03:06.106 diskimages-helper[96309:1726667] DIHelperHDID serveImage: set on IO thread=TRUE returned SUCCESS.
2021-08-29 01:03:06.106 diskimages-helper[96309:1726667] -processKernelRequest: will sleep received
2021-08-29 01:03:06.198 diskimages-helper[96309:1726665] _postflightMountPointsAfterDAMount: disk7 aborting because no mount point found.
2021-08-29 01:03:06.198 diskimages-helper[96309:1726665] allowMountReturningDictionary: detaching because no mountable filesystems.
Attaching…
Error 112 (no mountable file systems).
Finishing…
DIHLDiskImageAttach() returned 112
hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable file systems
```

Comment: what version of MacOS are you running? which version was used for creating the disk image? Make sure that your Mac does not run in safe mode, then can you kindly post the output of _hdiutil attach -verbose your.dmg_ ?

Comment: Please try _hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage -nomount your.dmg_ and then mount as you want.

Comment: I'm running Big Sur and the image was created using Catalina. My Mac is not in safe mode.

Comment: @slartibartfast I've added the output of hdiutil attach -verbose to my question, and I ran the hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage -nomount command, it just outputs /dev/disk7
What should I do after that?

Comment: mount it with: _diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk7_

Comment: @slartibartfast diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk7 outputs Volume(s) mounted successfully but nothing after that.

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   +247.6 GB   disk7
```

Comment: what happens after that if you open a terminal an execute: _cd /dev/disk7_ and then _ls -al_ ?

Comment: @slartibartfast cd: not a directory: /dev/disk7

Comment: sorry, please try _ls /dev/disk7_ to see the directories

Comment: Why is there no solution to this? I have a 12TB raw image (made with ddrescue), macOS Ventura 13.1, apple always says "uninitialised". But the data is there, how can I repair that HFS+ partition so that macOS recognizes it again?